# Howto prevent process crash on CRT error C++

Tags: c++, exception, crt

I have a 3rd party C library which can crashes on CRT error. In this case the whole process crashes. Is there any way to catch the all the CRT errors and prevent process termination.

Comment: Check the inputs to the library functions you use. Check the library state ((per-thread) initialization?). If all is well, file a bug with the library vendor.

Comment: Probably not. `__TRY` might work if you're on Windows or a signal on Unix depending on what the exact exception is. What is it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/969zc1ac.aspx Looks like you're SOL (2nd function from bottom, can't do it).

Comment: Libraries often crash when you're calling non-reentrant and non-threadsafe functions recursively or from multiple threads. Make sure you're not violating some not-so-obvious rule.

Comment: I've tried the __try option but it didn't help.

Comment: The library does the text parsing, and called with user input. It crushes on some texts, but I can do nothing about it.  What I want is to show user some message and close the thread, instead the whole server process crash.

Answer (score 4):

Preventing the crash is probably just delaying the problem.

Imagine that you could prevent the crash, but as a result, the user will save incorrect data back to the database, or corrupts data files, then you are just making the problem worse.

Instead, try to find out what the exact problem is:

- are you passing incorrect arguments to a function in the 3rd party library?
- or is it a bug in the 3rd party library?  Confront the library manufacturer with the bug.

Alternatively:

- try to find a work around to the problem
- find an alternative for the library

**EDIT:**
To be honest, I encountered the same situation last year with a 3rd party component.  What I did was the following:

First, use a _*try/*_except construction to catch the problem.  This only works if you known in which function call it exactly crashes.  It works like this:

```
__try
   {
   Some3rdPartyLibraryFunction();
   }
__except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
   {
   }
```

Second, to prevent further corruption of your application, make sure that the 3rd party library is not called anymore within your application.  E.g. suppose that the library is a reporting component, then if you encounter the crash, don't allow the user to open a report anymore, like this:

```
bool MyClass::openReport (char *reportname)
   {
   if (!reportModuleEnabled)
      return false;

   __try
      {
      OpenTheReport(reportname);
      }
   __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
      {
      // Tell the user about the problem and prevent further access to the library
      ShowMessage ("Sorry, no more reports");
      reportModuleEnabled = false;
      return false;
      }
   return true;
   }
```

Comment: If anything you should try and crash faster.

Comment: _try didn't help. The library does the text parsing, and called with user input. It crushes on some texts, but I can do nothing about it. What I want is to show user some message and close the thread, instead the whole server process crash

Comment: Which exception handling mechanism do you specify on the compiler's command line?  I use /EHsc and that seems to work correctly in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Your program runs on Windows? Have you tried wrapped the offending code with SEH?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes I've tried to add Unhandled exception filter, and to redirect the exception, but neither worked

Answer (score 1):

What a pity, nobody get the point.
The CRT error is nothing about SEH, so it can't be catch by _*try...*_except.
You should use the _set_invalid_parameter_handler and _set_purecall_handler functions handle the CRT error.

http://crashrpt.sourceforge.net/docs/html/exception_handling.html